# Unable to use value from two iterators in same loop

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I have the following python script where i want to take values from two iterators alternatively.

```
filename = "small"
with open(filename,'r') as plot_data:
    main_dict = dict()
    line_one = itertools.islice(plot_data, 0, None, 4)
    line_two = itertools.islice(plot_data, 2, None, 4)
    dictionary = defaultdict(list)
    #take values from iterators alternatively.
    for movie_name, movie_plot in itertools.izip(line_one, line_two):
        movie_plot = movie_plot.lower()
        words = re.findall(r'\w+', movie_plot, flags = re.UNICODE | re.LOCALE)
        elemStopW = filter(lambda x: x not in stopwords.words('english'), words)
        #list of words.
        print elemStopW
        for word in elemStopW:
            word = PorterStemmer().stem_word(word)
            dictionary[movie_name].append(word)
            main_dict[word] = len(main_dict)
    print main_dict
```

This script is not printing anything. I do not understand why. I do not want to merge the iterators as I want to use both the values in the same loop.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: To avoid some clearance(as in comments). The following script works fine

```
filename = "small"
with open(filename,'r') as plot_data:                    
        main_dict = dict()
        line_one = itertools.islice(plot_data, 0, None, 4)
        dictionary = defaultdict(list)                                                                      
        for movie_name in line_one:                                                           
                print movie_name
```

Comment: You've forgotton the file extension of `small`

Comment: what are the values of line_one and line_two?

Comment: @Haidro I am using Ubuntu so it is the name of my file.

Comment: @AlexanderAfanasiev: They are iterators. `line_one = itertools.islice(plot_data, 0, None, 4)` as shown in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably not do what you expect:

```
line_one = itertools.islice(plot_data, 0, None, 4)
line_two = itertools.islice(plot_data, 2, None, 4)
```

Since `plot_data` is a file object, reading from either iterator will advance the file - it will still be read sequentially rather than being read twice in parallel.

You can use `itertools.tee` to duplicate the file iterator so that it can be read twice in parallel:

```
plot1, plot2 = itertools.tee(plot_data, 2)
line_one = itertools.islice(plot1, 0, None, 4)
line_two = itertools.islice(plot2, 2, None, 4)
```

Note that if the positions of the two iterators can drift far from each other, this can take a lot of memory and you're better off opening the file twice. In this case, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam It looks OK but it depends on what the file looks like and what you need to do.